# Is it possible to get the size of a land/address/coordinates using Google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the size of an address using Google Maps JavaScript API. Is this possible?

I haven't found any documentation about this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't store the property boundaries of an address. If you click on an address in Google maps to see the "what's here" option, it will show you that the address is just an alias for a pair of longitude/latitude coordinates.